# EXT4-fs error (device loop0) ext4_mb_generate_buddy

Tags: linux, hard-drive, filesystems, ext4

I've been randomly getting theses in my /var/log/messages

```
[5747511.945300] EXT4-fs error (device loop0): ext4_mb_generate_buddy: EXT4-fs: group 1: 29505 blocks in bitmap, 29455 in gd
```

Not had any luck with google is this a drive failue or just a kernel glitch or a need to fsck?

kernel:

```
2.6.32-320.4.1.lve1.1.4.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 7 06:32:27 EST 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

the DC i think gave me a new drive over a few months ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a kernel bug. I've updated to kernel 3.0.57 from elrepo and it's all working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I my case the SD card of my Bananapi was corrupt (and the root filesystem was readonly).
I fixed that with fsck.